# Compiling code from conduit tutorial

Tags: haskell, conduit

I’m trying to understand code from http://www.yesodweb.com/book/conduits. After some fixes (like replacing `Resource` with `MonadResource`) it still won’t compile:

```
sumSink :: MonadResource m => Sink Int m Int
sumSink = CL.fold (+) 0

sum' :: [Int] -> Int
sum' input = runST $ runResourceT $ CL.sourceList input $$ sumSink
```

gives me the following error:

```
    Couldn't match type `GHC.ST.ST s' with `IO'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
        (GHC.ST.ST s) (GHC.ST.ST s),
        arising from the dependency `m -> b'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.Trans.Control'
      Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl IO (GHC.ST.ST s),
        arising from a use of `runResourceT'
        at D:\Works\stablename\test.hs:43:22-33
    In the expression: runResourceT
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `runResourceT $ CL.sourceList input $$ sumSink'
```

I’m using GHC 7.4.1 and conduit-0.4.2.

P.S. Is there any tutorial which isn’t broken / was written with conduit-0.4 in mind?

Comment: I was able to compile it after I deleted `runResourceT $` from `runST $ runResourceT $ CL.sourceList input $$ sumSink`. However, I still don’t understand anything.

Comment: conduit 0.5 has a new tutorial in the Haddocks. I'm hoping to release it some time next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- `Monad m` should be used instead of `Resource m`.
- `runResourceT` needs to be applied if a function like `sinkFile` was used somewhere in the chain, because `sinkFile` requires `MonadResource m` and there is no instance for `MonadResource IO`.